# How to use both Parse Path and Calculate Value in model?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, modelbuilder

Am I doing this wrong? I need to create hillshades for a set of raster, but I want the hillshades to retain the raster's original name. I used parse path for that, however there are names that are more than 13 characters so I used calculate value to edit the names. I used the expression r"%Value%".replace("-",""). It worked, I could see from the output that the value changed, however the hillshade does not adopt the naming even if I used %Value%. [image]

Here is my model. I preconditioned everything so that the hillshade will be the last process.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

From your graphic it looks like you should use `%output_value%`, instead of `%Value%`? Value is the original name of the raster.